# Custom theme sidebar

Tags: 14.04, themes

I'm new to linux, and I recently installed ubuntu on my notebook with dual boot. So, I find the ubuntu normal theme OK, but I'd rather have something different. I searched and found this one: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Vertex+-+Theme?content=166318. It's working just fine, but my sidebar is still the orange one, really really ugly. Is this right, or I installed it wrong? I'm using ubuntu 14.04. If I did something wrong, please, help me fix it :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Open this and in the launcer settings you can set a custom colour for the bar, hide it, make it see through etc..

Comment: This worked just fine, ty!